# “Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property.” error

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

While i was adding data to access database, i got error:

[image]

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    TB2.Clear()
    NameofG.Clear()
    NunberofG.Clear()
    UnitofG.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    pro = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Piyawat\Desktop\PPCC\Stock.accdb;"
    connstring = pro
    myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring
    If myconnection.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
        myconnection.Open()
    End If
    command = "insert into Stock([InvoiceID],[Type],[Item],[Amout],[Unit]) Value ('" & TB2.Text & "','" & CB1.Text & "','" & NameofG.Text & "','" & NunberofG.Text & "','" & UnitofG.Text & "')"
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(command, myconnection)
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("InvoiceID", CType(TB2.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Type", CType(CB1.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Item", CType(NameofG.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Amout", CType(NunberofG.Text, String)))
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New OleDbParameter("Unit", CType(UnitofG.Text, String)))
    MsgBox("Record Save")
    Try
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        cmd.Dispose()
        TB2.Clear()
        CB1.Text.DefaultIfEmpty
        NameofG.Clear()
        NunberofG.Clear()
        UnitofG.Clear()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox("Mistake")

    End Try

End Sub
```

How to fix the error? Please help. Thanks

Comment: By the looks of it, `myconnection.ConnectionString` is probably open when you are trying to set it to `connstring`?

Comment: What is so difficult to understand that your connection is already open? So, remove this: `myconnection.ConnectionString = connstring` as is something to be set to once and not every time you have to do with your commands.Also try to open your connection once (as how we see the connection variable  `myconnection ` is initialized somewhere else)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Not allowed to change the 'ConnectionString' property. The connection's current state is open](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/829051/not-allowed-to-change-the-connectionstring-property-the-connections-current)

Comment: your syntax for the SQL and the parameters you have are all wrong - they will not work. See my code below. The params means you do NOT have to palce the text box values in the sql string - and you don't need all thoe quotes, single quotes etc. See below.

Answer (score 0):

I would AWAYS ensure that after you use the connection, you close it.

however, you can get .net to automatics do this for you.

Also, go into project->settings and add your connection string there - that way you NEVER have to place or have connection strings in code - (bad idea).

Hence, your code should and would look like this:

```
    Dim strSQL As String = "INSERT INTO Stock([InvoiceID],[Type],[Item],[Amout],[Unit]) " &
                           "VALUES (@TB2, @CB1, @NameofG, @NunberofG, @UnitofG)"

    Using cmd As New OleDbCommand(strSQL, New OleDbConnection(My.Settings.Test44))


        cmd.Parameters.Add("@TB2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = TB2.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@CB1", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = CB1.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("NameofG", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = NameofG.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@NumberofG", OleDbType.Integer).Value = NunberofG.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@UnitofG", OleDbType.Integer).Value = UnitOfG.Text

        cmd.Connection.Open()

        Try
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            MsgBox("Record Save")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error = " & ex.Message)
        End Try


    End Using
```

note the following:

No messy string concentation.

No messy quotes for strings, non quotes for numbers.

clean easy to read.

use parmaters - safe.

And with a using block, we do NOT have to dispose or close the conneciton - it is automatic for you. So ALWAYS assume it is closed.

note how we don't have a seperate conneciton object - don't need one.

note how the command object is REALLY nice.
The command object has:

```
a connection object - you don't need to create a new one

command text

a reader!!! - you can use command object - no need to load + create a reader
```

Answer (score 0):

I moved the database code to a separate method.

Starting with the user interface code, you first want to validate the input. I had to guess at the datatypes because your code made them all look like strings. I hope this is not true.

It seems you got mixed up with Parameters. I am very glad that you tried to used them but they don't appear in your sql string so they are not being used. You don't want to concatenate strings with user input because it risks sql injection.

The @ sign preceding the parameter names is just a convention that makes it easy to recognize.

You need to keep database objects local to the method where they are used. That way they can be closed and disposed with Using...End Using blocks as quickly as possible.

```
Private ConStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Piyawat\Desktop\PPCC\Stock.accdb;" '"Your connection string"

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    'Validate input
    Dim ID As Integer
    Dim Amt As Decimal
    Dim Unt As Integer
    Dim message = "Please enter a number for the"
    If Not Integer.TryParse(TB2.Text, ID) Then
        MessageBox.Show(message & " Invoice ID.")
        Return
    End If
    If Not Decimal.TryParse(NunberofG.Text, Amt) Then
        MessageBox.Show(message & " Amount.")
        Return
    End If
    If Not Integer.TryParse(UnitofG.Text, Unt) Then
        MessageBox.Show(message & " Unit")
        Return
    End If
    'Call the insert method
    Try
        InsertInvoice(ID, CB1.Text, NameofG.Text, Amt, )
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
        Return
    End Try
    MessageBox.Show("Record Saved")
    TB2.Clear()
    CB1.Text.DefaultIfEmpty
    NameofG.Clear()
    NunberofG.Clear()
    UnitofG.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub InsertInvoice(InvoiceID As Integer, Type As String, Item As String, Amount As Decimal, Unit As Integer)
    Dim Command = "insert into Stock([InvoiceID],[Type],[Item],[Amout],[Unit]) Value (@InvoiceID,@Type,@Item,@Amount,@Unit)"
    Using myconnection As New OleDbConnection(ConStr),
            cmd As New OleDbCommand(Command, myconnection)
        With cmd.Parameters
            .Add("@InvoiceID", OleDbType.Integer).Value = InvoiceID
            .Add("@Type", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Type
            .Add("@Item", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = Item
            .Add("@Amout", OleDbType.Decimal).Value = Amount
            .Add("@Unit", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Unit
        End With
    End Using
End Sub
```